# AWS Lambda with Kinesis stream 2 shards

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I would like to use AWS Lambda with Kinesis stream 2 shards and I want lambda to process the tasks in kinesis in order but with 2 shards I found out lambda didn't keep the processing in order, anyone can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering is guaranteed within shards , not across shards

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how can I manage the distribution of the tasks across shards to keep the order of the tasks?

Comment: One solution is to add timestamp to every task before adding it or during creation